# Есть поставщики , необходимо как-то автоматически подгружать данные из их гугл таблиц в единую БД

Tags: python, база-данных, google-spreadsheet

Необходимо реализовать автозагрузку и обновление данных из Гугл таблиц поставщиков в нашу БД программы ,стэк Python ,с бд ещё не определились и методом коннекта тоже ,посоветуйте пожалуйста как это лучше реализовать и чем пользоваться?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.